# Firebase authentication! I'm able to move to home page even if i enter a non registered user

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I've successfully added firebase to my flutter2.0 project. I've enables authentication also.I'm able to register a new user also. But the logic to move to home page after authentication is not working. I'm able to login even if I enter a wrong user. I want if I enter proper user then I should navigate to home page, but if the user is not registered it one should not be able to navigate to next page. ie..the basic use of authentication.
But it's not happening here. I'm able to navigate to next place even if I enter wrong user.

```
Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email:email,
    password:password,
  );
  
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    print('No user found for that email.');
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
  }
}
  }

  Future newAccount(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

//this is how I can this function and try to navigate to next page.
void logMeIn() {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      authMethods
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(usernameTextEditingContoller.text,
              passwordTextEditingContoller.text)
          .then((value) {
            print('value is: ');
        print(value);
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return Home();
        }));
      });
    }
  }**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns a `UserCredential` object.

In your logic, you are using `.then((value) {...etc})`

This `value` is the result of `signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

Try changing your logic to this:

```
authMethods
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(usernameTextEditingContoller.text,
              passwordTextEditingContoller.text)
          .then((value) {
            print('value is: ');
        print(value);
        if(value.user ==null) return "Error in authentication"; // this will prevent your function form going further down the navigation if the usercredential doesn't have a valid user.
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return Home();
```

Comment: W/System  (25852): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter (25852): value is:
I/flutter (25852): null
E/flutter (25852): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'user' was called on null.
E/flutter (25852): Receiver: null
E/flutter (25852): Tried calling: user

Comment: `The getter 'user'` this means that the UserCredential was not generated. Change the if statement to `if (value==null)` , it should work.

Comment: 2
W/System  (25852): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter (25852): value is:
I/flutter (25852): null
E/flutter (25852): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'user' was called on null.
E/flutter (25852): Receiver: null
E/flutter (25852): Tried calling: user

Comment: This error is from someplace else, not the code you posted. We arent calling user in the above code, we removed it and are using now `value==null` not `value.user`. Check where you are calling user unconditionally, after the sign in